# Unit testing mapper setup

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I have a map-reduce job for which I need to write a unit test for the `setup` method of the mapper. The `setup()` is `protected` and hence I cannot access it or invoke it in the unit test class.

I have 2 questions. Please bear in mind that I am new to the map-reduce framework.

1. When a hadoop `job` is created and a mapper is defined, how does hadoop invoke the `setup` method of the mapper?
2. For unit testing, how can I invoke the `setup` method without changing the access qualifier of `setup` in the mapper class?